# Are there any examples for how to integrate iAds into an application?

Tags: iphone, iad

I'm looking for sample code or tutorials on how to implement iAds in my iPhone application.  Can anyone guide me to any resources about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iAd Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/index.html) has detailed information on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder just drag and drop your ad into the window. In Xcode, right click on your frameworks folder and add the iAd.framework. It's really that simple.

For more advanced things, like hiding and rotating ads, you could start with the WWDC session videos if you're a registered developer. If you're not, get an account because it's a very nice program and you need it to get your apps published.

The session 112 video is a step-by-step, I used it to get my own iAds running, but otherwise try this link [iAds](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/index.html). You still need a developer account.

Comment: Also, the iAds service will start showing live ads on the first of July, you're right. When you're testing your app, you'll only see Apple's "Test Ad" though.