# How do I use implement iAd into my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

I've been working on a app that I want to earn money from, but nobody would buy it if it costed money.  Does anyone know any tutorials, or know themselves, how to get iAd into an app?  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any examples for how to integrate iAds into an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115920/are-there-any-examples-for-how-to-integrate-iads-into-an-application)

Comment: I'd never even seen that before.

Comment: can you help me on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953418/implementation-for-iad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something to get you started:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 2):

To implement iAds, you need to use ADBannerView and implement some delegate methods of ADBannerViewDelegate. I stumbled upon this tutorial and it helped me greatly:

http://www.ioslearner.com/implement-iads-tutorial-iphone-ipad-sdk/

All the best!